# Setting up Node.js on visual studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, installation

I'm very new to coding and woukd love to learn but the problem is that I have previously followed a tutorial on how to set up python on visual studio and now i don't know how to set up nodejs on it
I desperately need it if anyone can provide some help. I've already installed nodejs, i just don't know how to use it on vs

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? I think you mean VSCode but a little clarity might help

Comment: It's Visual studio code

Comment: All done; saved a file .js and all worked out fine thank you!

Answer (score -1):

if you already installed nodejs that's pretty all. To run node you use cmd/terminal, in vs you can press "ctrl+`" to open terminal. then you type "node filename" to run it.

Comment: I think you mean VS Code not VS just like the OP